# Connectivity to mainframes using JMS

Tags: java, jms, mainframe

We are currently using WebSphere MQ to fetch data from mainframes and at times face issues on the MQ side.

I would like to know if there is someway to circumvent MQ and use JMS instead to fetch data from mainframes. We use WebSphere Application Server 6.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but JMS is only a driver interface not a queue manager implementation.

Between JMS and a queue manager there is the same difference than between JDBC and a database.

LLP, Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use JMS on the java side which will end up wrapping calls to MQ.  You just have to be careful about message headers.
Replacing MQ with another messaging infrastructure is dependent on what the mainframe can talk to, since I imagine you don't have much control over that, right?  MQ is often chosen because of it's support by IBM's mainframe systems.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Please find the logic,

1. We have to establish the connection to the Server using
   ConnectionFactory, Connection and Session
2. We need to create Queue reference using Queue
3. Need to create an object for Message which we are planning to send to the Queue using TextMessage
4. We have to create objects to interact with Queue. Here, MessageProducer used to send the  message which we have created at step 3 and MessageConsumer used to receive the response

Please find the below code for implementation,

```
//Instantiate a Sun Java(tm) System Message Queue ConnectionFactory 
ConnectionFactory myConnFactory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();

String h = "HOSTNAME";
String p = "PORTNO";

// Set imqAddressList property
((com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory)myConnFactory).setProperty(
com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList,
new StringBuffer().append("mq://").append(h).append(":").append(p).append("/jms").toString());

//Create a connection to the Sun Java(tm) System Message Queue Message Service.
Connection myConn = myConnFactory.createConnection();

//Start the Connection created in step 3.
myConn.start();

//Create a session within the connection.
Session mySess = myConn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

//Instantiate a Sun Java(tm) System Message Queue Destination administered object.
Queue myQueue = new com.sun.messaging.Queue("<MODULENAME>");

//Create a message producer.
MessageProducer myMsgProducer = mySess.createProducer(myQueue);

//Create and send a message to the queue.
TextMessage myTextMsg = mySess.createTextMessage();
myTextMsg.setText("<message>");

System.out.println("Sending Message: " + myTextMsg.getText());
myMsgProducer.send(myTextMsg);

//Create a message consumer.
MessageConsumer myMsgConsumer = mySess.createConsumer(myQueue);

//Start the Connection created in step 3.
myConn.start();

//Receive a message from the queue.
Message msg = myMsgConsumer.receive();

//Retreive the contents of the message.
if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) msg;
System.out.println("Read Message: " + txtMsg.getText());
}

//Close the session and connection resources.
mySess.close();
myConn.close();
```